# xml serialization and encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

i want the xml encoding to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
```

To generate encoding like `encoding="windows-1252"` I wrote this code.

```
var myns = OS.xmlns;
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false
    };
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(string.Empty, myns);
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(OS.GetType(), myns);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, OS,ns);
    }
    xmlString= stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

But I am still not getting my expected encoding what am I missing?  Please guide me to generate encoding like `encoding="windows-1252"?`.  What do I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you output the XML directly to a [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) (through a [StringBuilder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) or a [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx)) you'll always get UTF-8 or UTF-16 encondings. This is because [strings in .NET are internally represented as Unicode characters](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx).

In order to get the proper encoding you'll have to **switch to a binary output**, such as a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).

Here's a quick example:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
};

using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(buffer, settings))
    {
        writer.WriteRaw("<sample></sample>");
    }

    buffer.Position = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(buffer))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [C# in Depth: Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)